# How to store the data from the DatePicker in Flutter

Tags: android, datetime, flutter, dart, store

how do i store a the date which is set by the user such that every time, he/she opens the application, the date that is selected remains there and isn't refreshed to the initial date every time. Furthermore, how do I transfer the data that I have from say a supposed Screen1.dart to a Screen2.dart

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime(2101));
if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;
  });
}
```

The data being the `selectedDate`. And the transfer refers to using this given data elsewhere to say find the difference between two chosen dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use shared preferences to achieve that, here is an example with a similar case as yours:

[How to save dateformat with sharedpref in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112105/how-to-save-dateformat-with-sharedpref-in-flutter)

> saving: prefs.setString('dateTimeLastClicked', currentTime);
>
> loading: reftime_string = prefs.getString('dateTimeLastClicked');

Comment: But how do I save this if let's say the code that I have is on another .dart file, and the structure is a bit complicated.

For example:

` Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}"),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              child: Text('Select date'),`
And I wish to parse the code into this calculating file:
`final date1 = DateTime(2000, 10, 12);
final date2 = DateTime.now();
final difference = date2.difference(date1).inDays;`

Comment: When the date is selected you save it on the shared preferences in Screen1.dart, then in Screen2.dart you can access the shared preferences and get what you saved before

Comment: I see, so the shared pref wont change even if the user closes the application right according to this https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences.

Thanks :)

Comment: How does one initialize it though? I tried trying the example on shared_pref but im constantly getting errors haha

Comment: Check the code on the question of the link I shared in my answer, you need to do something like this: SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();